# How can I tweak this so it will accept .flv files?

Tags: php, mysql, flv

I want to tweak this so it can handle .flv files, can anyone please help me?

```
    <?php
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Also, is there anything I need to change anywhere else on my server so that I can handle .flv files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does **handle** means? This is upload script, it can be any file and there is no MySQL in what you have posted here. Please be more clear with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of video/flv, I had to do this for my site:

```
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/x-flv")
```

And then you probably want to make sure this is in your Apache config file:

```
AddType video/x-flv .flv
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
```

Obviously those lines will be different if you are using IIS or something similar, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Add another OR condition in first IF...
`|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/flv")`

Answer (score 1):

These are all the suppored web video formats that can be embed into webpage :

```
if ((
 ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/x-flv")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/ogg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/quicktime")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/webm")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/x-ms-wmv")
)
```